# SQL or filesystem for FAST storing files/BLOBs?

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, filesystems, blob

I have an app that stores quite a lot of publications as files on filesystem, using nested dirs like "6/0/3/6/....". Files are not huge (.jpg, .pdf, similar documents), there's "just" a lot of them, running into GB hundreds. Once stored in fs, they typically are never rewritten, just served over http.

Searching, versioning through such files is *painfully* slow. Copying such dirs is also rather cumbersome.

This got me thinking: would it not be better to store such data as BLOBs in db (my app is using postgres for various purposes anyway).

Which one -- fs or scalable sql db -- could perform better all around? Or would PG collapse under so much weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental backup is *much* easier with the filesystem. So is recovering from partial damage.  Versioning is pretty easy to do on top of the file system so long as you don't need atomic change sets, only individual file versioning.

On the other hand, using the DB gets you transactional behaviour - atomic commit, multiple concurrent consistent snapshots, etc. It costs you disk storage efficiency and it adds overhead to access. It means you can't just `sendfile()` the data directly from the file system, you must do *several* memory copies and some encoding just to get and send the file.

For a high performance server the file system is almost certainly going to win unless you really *need* atomic commit and the simultaneous consistent visibility of multiple versions.

There are lots of related past questions you should probably read too, most concerning whether it's better to store images in the DB or on the file system.

Comment: "Incremental backup is much easier with the filesystem." -- I don't quite get that, after all how hard it is to store timestamp for a BLOB/BYTEA?

Sure, one has to write this himself while one gets awesome stuff like rsync out of box. But then it's integrated with your app while keeping blobs and files in sync can be tricky.

Comment: "Versioning is pretty easy to do on top of the file system so long as you don't need atomic change sets, only individual file versioning." -- erm I just got burned on this one. I have done "git add ." for a dir with publications in question and git after hanging there for hours quit due to exhausting diskspace (although I had free space like 40% of the partition).

I have the impression -- mistaken maybe -- that doing SELECT on timestamps for blobs and then sending the blobs over network to backup system might be faster.

Comment: "For a high performance server the file system is almost certainly going to win unless you really need atomic commit and the simultaneous consistent visibility of multiple versions." -- possibly, but I'd love to do some reliable benchmarks in conditions resembling production systems. The best I found was 1993 paper on citeseer for PG and fs comparison, not quite the best resource nowadays.

Comment: "There are lots of related past questions you should probably read too, most concerning whether it's better to store images in the DB or on the file system." -- Sure, I've read those. And the conclusions I've read all fall in different directions, and they are completely contradictory, and most rely on handwaving and claims that are plausible rather than proven.

Hence I asked this question *again*.

I feel like I will have to do some testing myself to resolve this issue!

Comment: just look at answers to this question -- your answer is near opposite to the one given by Christophe above.

Comment: On versioning, I mean app-level versioning where the user level visible file "fred.jpg" is "fred.jpg.1", "fred.jpg.2", etc in the filesystem with appropriate refs to the database. You garbage collect unreferenced files occasionally. Works well and is pretty simple. Trying to use software revision control management tools for versioning trees of binary files in an application won't work wonderfully, no.

Comment: Re performance: A key part of the matter is this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html . Not possible from PostgreSQL, big help for serving static files via (eg) lighthttpd. Even if you need some server log to decide what file to send, once you'e picked it you just tell the kernel "dump this file down the socket to the client".

Comment: I think you've already learned the most important thing: There's no one right answer to this. "It depends" on workload, hardware, details of exactly what your requirements and goals are, etc etc etc. I probably should've just close-voted it "Not constructive, open ended" per the Stack Overflow FAQ. You're quite right that the only solid way to get an answer is **test it for your exact situation**.

Answer (score 1):

FileSystem has other big disadvantages :

1. You can get problems with user rights
2. Not atomic
3. Slow

When dealing with BLOB < 1GB, I would 100% store them in database since all good system databases can handle BLOB properly. (They store it in a different manner than structured data but it is not visible to you)

By the way, when you read on http://www.postgresql.org/about/

Maximum Database Size => Unlimited